# Obtener el nùmero del dia del mes mediante el numero del dia del año

Tags: java

sigo aprendiendo java. Estoy haciendo un programa donde tome 5 nombres, 5 cumpleaños (mes y día del mes). Después tomaría el cumpleaños y diría el día del año.

Para eso cree un array con los respectivos días, al final de cada mes hasta 365, pero estoy atascado ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el numero del mes saque el elemento del array de los días del año?

De esa manera si es febrero 14 seria un 2 y 14, quiero tomar que tome el valor 31, y sumarlo mas el 14 para que sea 45, y ese seria el numero del año.
en pocas palabras seria 2,14 y el resultado seria 45.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class practice2 {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         Scanner input;
        int[]  num2 = {31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334,365};       
         int value = 5;    
                input = new Scanner(System.in);
                String[] words = new String[value];
                int[] month = new int [value];
                int [] num = new int[value];
                for (int x = 0; x < value; x++) {

                    System.out.println("Enter a name?");
                    words[x] = input.next();
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));

                    System.out.println("Birth month?(1 to 12) ");
                    month[x] = input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(month));

                    System.out.println("day of the month?(1 to 31) ");
                    num[x] = input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
                    }
                }
     }
```

muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: ¿Podrias poner un ejemplo de los resultado que quieres obtener? No me queda muy claro lo que buscas.

Comment: listo eh editado la pregunta espero quede un poco mas claro,

Comment: Sabes que no todos los años tienen la misma cantidad de días, ¿verdad?

Comment: lo se por eso previamente los sume, ya que 31+28=59 y asi sucecibamente de modo que si selecciona marzo tomaria el la suma de los dos meses anteriores(59) mas el dia de marzo seleccionado seria igual al numero del año

Comment: No estoy hablando de los meses. Digo que no todos los años tienen 365 días.

Comment: lo se pero para este programa solo tomare el año de 365 dias ya que sigo aprendiendo java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que buscas es sencilla. Solo necesitas llamar con el mes que introdujiste y pasarlo al arreglo de esta manera:

```
int[]  num2 = {31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334,365};       

    int mes = 2;
    int dia = 14;

    int sumaDias;
    if (mes==1) {
        //ESTO ES NECESARIO POR QUE SI TE DAN MES UNO Y 19 SOLO NECESITAS EL 19.
        sumaDias = dia;
    }else {
        //ESTE OBTIENE LA SUMA DEL MES ANTERIOR Y SUMA LOS DIAS DEL MES INTRODUCIDO.
        sumaDias = num2[mes-1-1] + dia;
    }

    System.out.println(sumaDias);
```

Esto es así por que ya te diste a la tarea de sumar todos los días en cada posición del arreglo.

Por aquello de que los arreglos empiezan en `0` pongo `-1-1`. El ségundo menos uno es para que te des cuenta de que lo que te interesa no es el mes real que te dan, si no el valor de días anterior.

Tu quieres el 14 de febrero. Necesitas obtener la súma de enero que es `num[0] + diaIntroducido`.

Answer (score 0):

Hay una clase muy útil para todo lo referente a fechas.

java.util.GregorianCalendar, que extiende a java.util.Calendar.

Te recomiendo leas las instrucciones de ambas.

Te comparto un método como ejemplo para que veas la utilidad de estas clases.

```
public int dameMaximoDiasEnMes(int año, int mes) {
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    gc.set(Calendar.YEAR,año);
    gc.set(Calendar.MONTH,mes-1); //ojo, enero es cero, por eso resto uno
    return gc.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE);
}
```

Este método le pones el año y el mes y te dice cuanto es el número máximo de días que puede tener dicho mes. Así no tienes que iterar, ni calcular años bisiestos, etc., esta clase tiene demasiados métodos y parámetros para apoyarte con esos cálculos. Por ejemplo, te dice de una fecha que día de la semana es, que semana del mes, o del año, etc., muchas opciones.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias esto sera de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Yo he utilizado otra manera, ya que en los años bisiestos febrero no calza.

Adjunto mi código:

```
Public int cantidadDias(Date fecha){
    Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date primerDia = new Date();
    int cantDias;

    try {
        primerDia = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
                .parse("01/" + new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy").format(fecha));
        calendario.setTime(primerDia);
        calendario.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        calendario.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);

        cantDias = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("d")
                .format(calendario.getTime()).toString());

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        cantidadDias = 0;
    }

    return cantDias;
}
```